# H2 database tcp remote via Shell: SQL Exception: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"

Tags: java, tomcat, h2

Java (Servlet 3.1 webapp in Tomcat 8.5):

```
org.h2.tools.Server web = Server.createWebServer("-ifExists", "-webSSL", "-webPort", "8085", "-webAllowOthers").start();
org.h2.tools.Server tcp = Server.createTcpServer("-ifExists", "-tcpSSL", "-tcpPort", "8089", "-tcpAllowOthers").start();
```

The H2 Console runs fine over the web after making adjustment in the properties file.
Running Shell from command line in a **different machine**:

```
$ java -cp h2-2.1.210.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
```

URLs I've tried (all failed):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net//Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net:8089/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net:8089/file:/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net:8089//file:Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:ssl://mySite.net//Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:ssl://mySite.net/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:ssl://mySite.net:8089/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:ssl://mySite.net:8089/file:/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:ssl://mySite.net:8089//file:Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
```

Shell gives same result every time (no log elsewhere to be found):

```
SQL Exception: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"
```

No lock on the db was seen.
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
After opening port 8089 on router, the following formats work:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net:8089/file:/Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
jdbc:h2:tcp://mySite.net:8089//Users/xyz/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/database/myh2db;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MODE=MySQL;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
```

Any URL using ssl fails with:

```
SQL Exception: Connection is broken: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Since port 8443 is already in use, I am unable to bind it to the TcpServer for ssl. I need to learn to open up another SSL/HTTPS port on Tomcat for H2 tcpSSL.

Comment: Is `mySite.net:8089` reachable? You can test with a browser, telnet or netcat

Comment: Thank you! I did indeed neglect to open up port 8089 on the router. Now that it is open, the tcp protocol works (using either /file: or "//" preceding the resource path root). ssl fails.